# Question was deleted referring to the false fact

Tags: discussion, support, questions, deleted-questions

This question: https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/7971/how-to-install-cx-oracle-python-db-driver?noredirect=1#comment36146_7971 was deleted by user 'goldilocks' with a comment: "They do now, so I presume this question is moot -- deleted."

According to this SO question: [Oracle Instant Client for ARM based Debian device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26167682/oracle-instant-client-for-arm-based-debian-device), this is NOT true, i.e. there is no ARM oracle db client available.

So:

1. If the client is indeed available if would be fair to add a comment to the SO answer as well.
2. If this is not true, can you please undelete my original question?

Comment: Should this be posted on meta.raspberrypi.se.com?

Answer (score 2):

My bad.  I was doing some housekeeping, saw that (which has gone unanswered for almost two years), read your comment "Oracle doesn't support ARM-based platforms" and thought, "Sure they do -- there's Oracle Java for ARM", overlooking the fact that you meant a specific DB client.

Undeleted!